# Grepping and grouping for errors in log files

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

I'm on Linux (and also sometimes on AIX) and have a bunch of log files in a folder. I have a grep command that will filter out all of the ERRORs in a format as follows.

```
CreateOrder_hostname_tee.log:2015-09-29 15:42:06,715:ERROR  :Thread-26_CreateOrder: [1443555726715] Error1  [system]: Class1
CreateOrder_hostname_tee.log:2015-09-29 15:42:06,715:ERROR  :Thread-15_CreateOrder: [1443555726715] Error1  [system]: Class1
CreateOrder_hostname_tee.log:2015-09-29 15:42:06,715:ERROR  :Thread-28_CreateOrder: [1443555726715] Error2  [system]: Class2
ScheduleOrder_hostname_tee.log:2015-09-30 03:55:05,011:ERROR  :Thread-5_ScheduleOrder: [1443599705009] Error3  [system]: Class3
```

Is it possible using some combination of grep/awk/sed to get the above data in a format like this?

```
API: Error: Count
CreateOrder: Error1: 50
CreateOrder: Error2: 50
ScheduleOrder: Error3: 50
```

If not, would it be possible to get the format like this? Then I could use wc or similar to count the distinct errors.

```
API: Date: Error
CreateOrder: 2015-09-29 15:42:06,715: Error1
CreateOrder: 2015-09-29 15:42:06,715: Error2
ScheduleOrder: 2015-09-29 15:42:06,715: Error3
```

EDIT 1:

The error could be any string (including spaces). Basically, anything in between the brackets below should be displayed.

```
[1443555726715] Error1: This is an error with description.  [system]: Class1
```

Comment: Where do the `50`s come from?  I don't see them in the input.

Comment: @Alfe: I presume it's the number of occurences of that error type

Comment: That's just a count of the number of times the error has occurred - I was making up dummy data.

Comment: Are the error starting patterns known before hand? (like the CreateOrder, ScheduleOrder, etc) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input=$(your grep command)
formatted=$(
  echo "$input" |
    sed 's/^\([^_]*\).*[0-9]*\] \([^[]*[^\[ ]\).*/\1: \2/'
)
kinds=$(echo "$formatted" | sort -u)
while IFS= read kind
do
  count=$(echo "$formatted" | grep "$kind" | wc -l)
  echo "$kind: $count"
done <<< "$kinds"
```

For the input given in your question, this gives this output:

```
CreateOrder: Error1: 2
CreateOrder: Error2: 1
ScheduleOrder: Error3: 1
```

Everything is done in memory, so it might not be feasible for very large data structures (dozens or hundreds of megabytes).  But in these cases you can use temporary files instead of shell variables (e. g. `echo "$input" | sed … > formatted.tmp` and `sort -u formatted.tmp > kinds.tmp` etc.).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is very close but the errors might have spaces in them and I don't think this handles that as I only get the piece of the error string before the space. Is it possible to get the full error including any spaces?

Comment: My clairvoyance is low today :-}  Meaning: I cannot guess what you don't tell me.  You need to adjust the regexp then.  Please give more examples to show what input should be converted to what output.  I changed the answer according to what I now understand what the spec is.

Comment: My apologies, I have added a statement saying the error string could be anything and should be grabbed from in between the brackets.

Comment: I changed my answer to take everything up to the last non-space before the next opening bracket.

Comment: Thank you for the update, this is just what I wanted. I'll study your example and try to generate option 2 in my question above and if needed, ask a new question.

Comment: The trick is always the same:  Describe the complete(!) line with a regular expression, make groups out of the parts which you want to use (with the parentheses), and replace that line with these groups.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a simple bash script where you could add new patterns easily, the usage is:

```
myscript.sh logfile
```

Script code:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATTERN_1=(CreateOrder Error1)
PATTERN_2=(CreateOrder Error2)
PATTERN_3=(ScheduleOrder Error3)

function get_pattern_count {
    COUNT=$(grep -E ".+$1.+$2.+" $3 | wc -l)
    echo $1 " : " $2 : $COUNT
}

echo "API: Error: Count"
get_pattern_count ${PATTERN_1[0]} ${PATTERN_1[1]} $1
get_pattern_count ${PATTERN_2[0]} ${PATTERN_2[1]} $1
get_pattern_count ${PATTERN_3[0]} ${PATTERN_3[1]} $1
```

Comment: I assume PO does not know which patterns might occur.

Comment: You mean the user doesn't know the errors syntax starting like 'CreateOrder', etc? so this could be anything?

Comment: Yes, I mean that.   And you really should start using `"$x"` instead of `$x`.  Otherwise you will be in trouble as soon as your `$x` contains a space or other funny character.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I think the error patterns are known before hand.

Answer (score 0):

This solution sorts the output alphabetically by API
At the beginning, it prints the header line
Looping over each line, it searches for a /regular expression/
If found, it stores the result into a hash
At the end, it sorts the keys of the hash, and prints the results

`perl -lane 'BEGIN{print "API: Error: Count"} if(/^([^_]+).*\]\s*(Error[^\[]+)\[/){$h{"$1: $2:"}++} END{for $k (sort keys %h){ print "$k $h{$k}"}}' log`

input:

```
CreateOrder_hostname_tee.log:2015-09-29 15:42:06,715:ERROR  :Thread-26_CreateOrder: [1443555726715] Error1  [system]: Class1
CreateOrder_hostname_tee.log:2015-09-29 15:42:06,715:ERROR  :Thread-15_CreateOrder: [1443555726715] Error1  [system]: Class1
CreateOrder_hostname_tee.log:2015-09-29 15:42:06,715:ERROR  :Thread-28_CreateOrder: [1443555726715] Error2  [system]: Class2
ScheduleOrder_hostname_tee.log:2015-09-30 03:55:05,011:ERROR  :Thread-5_ScheduleOrder: [1443599705009] Error3  [system]: Class3
ScheduleOrder_hostname_tee.log:2015-09-30 03:55:05,011:ERROR  :Thread-5_ScheduleOrder: [1443555726715] Error1: This is an error with description.  [system]: Class1
```

output:

```
API: Error: Count
CreateOrder: Error1  : 2
CreateOrder: Error2  : 1
ScheduleOrder: Error1: This is an error with description.  : 1
ScheduleOrder: Error3  : 1
```